# Update Master Table automatically from several separate Worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automatic-update

I have 6 separate worksheets that are updated every week by 6 different people manually. The process is archaic as there is a new sheet template for each week (4 separate excel files that contain 5 tables x 6 area sheets. I manually enter the data into a master tracker.

I am trying to figure out a workflow that automates this process where when each of these 6 data sheets is updated, the master sheet would automatically update itself. The data sheets and the master tracker are nearly identical as per their inputs.

I have provided sample data and the master tracker via this file download link for anyone who is curious: [enter link description here](https://ufile.io/ha7qq)

Comment: Are you updating the entire sheet to Master or some columns,,, and is there any criteria to update or is like new data paste over old one?

Comment: Rajesh S, That is correct. The 6 sheets are the entire master tracker essentially, just that the tracker spreads over the entire year broken down month and week.My intent is that for whatever date reflective of the data sheets that would pop up in the same date breakdown in the master.

Comment: I can suggest you VBA(macro) to update Master sheet from other sheets when edited,, but this processes will work when all sheets are identical. Just confirm will this work for you?

Comment: I will try whatever I need to make this work. I am also more than willing to change the structure of my sheets to accommodate the VBA macro so let me know if you would recommend anything along that line. I have no experience with VBA or macros as yet so this would be a great learning experience. Would it be okay to move this to chat? Thanks Rajesh S!